# How to use macros and variables in Xib?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

For example：

```
// I define a macro
#define exampleMacro @"some text"
```

I want this macro is written in the text box on the label above xib，Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. A Xib file is just an XML with a special format. You'll have to do this in Objective C, for example in `viewDidLoad:`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    aLabel.text = exampleMacro;
}
```

Also:

1. try to use `CAPITAL_LETTERS` for your macro names, this will improve recognizability.
2. don't use macros for this purpose at all - learn how to use [`.strings`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html) files.